# How to retrieve the text from a className in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access the words from the className muichip label.

I returned 14 results which are undefined in the console log. But I am not to sure why they are not returning back as a string? Can anyone help me?

```
 const unitTests = unitTestTemplates.map((item) => {
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("MuiChip-label").innerHTML)
          
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, question already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` return a list of elements ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)), so you should iterate through that list

```
document.getElementsByClassName("MuiChip-label").forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.innerHTML)
})
```

Comment: Great, thankyou! Say if I wanted to check if the text contains a word, how should i do this? Would doing .includes work?

Comment: @bloombloom if you want to check text only, regardless of the tag, then you should use `element.innerText.includes(...)` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText))